# StreamGobbler with javax.resource.spi.work.Work inside an EJB

Tags: jboss, stream, ejb

I have a Stateless EJB that does a `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` and uses a StreamGlobbers around the process inputStream and errorStream. Each one of the gobblers has a `javax.resource.spi.work.Work` related (started by a WorkManager).

My question is: Knowing the stream gobbler syncronize the reading with the worker, am I breaking any ejb 3.0 contract? Because I use lots of waits, notifies and interrupts.

Also, in order to prevent the system to wait forever on the `process.waitFor();`, I've created a `java.util.Timer` that causes the current Thread to interrupt.

I'm using JBoss AS 4.2.3.GA.

PS: StreamGobbler is basically a thread that keep reading from another stream.